# how to set connection pool in context file?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

i have develop webpage using simple servlet. here i have using one context file for declare the DB connection like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/red" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      maxActive="50" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="3600000"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="3600000"
      maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root"
      password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/red"
      defaultAutoCommit="false" >

</Resource>
</Context>
```

and i have configured in web.xml

```
  <resource-ref>
    <description>Mysql datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/red</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

in servlet page

```
    Context ctx=new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/red");
    con=ds.getConnection();
    state=con.createStatement();
    rs=state.executeQuery(s);
    rs.close();
    con.close();
    ctx.close();
```

my problem is when the connection establish more than 50 times error occurs like this :

```
   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
```

java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1171)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)

Context ctx=new InitialContext();
   120: DataSource ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/red");
   121: con=ds.getConnection();

Answer (score 0):

try to execute 
`SET GLOBAL max_connections = 500;` in MySQL or restart MySQL.
This link will help you resolving the issue
[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)